# Joining range of vectors does not give a range

Tags: c++, gcc, std-ranges, c++23

I am trying to do transform over cartesian product, flattening edges in the end. I receive a result whish is not a range and this is the problem:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    auto indicies = std::views::iota(0, 3);

    auto coords = std::views::cartesian_product(indicies, indicies);

    auto edges = coords | std::views::transform([](const auto& coord) {
        using Coord = std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>;
        using Edge = std::pair<Coord, Coord>;
        std::vector<Edge> ret;
        const auto& [x, y] = coord;
        auto curr = Coord{x, y};
        if (x + 1 < 3) {
            auto dest = Coord{x + 1, y};
            ret.emplace_back(curr, dest);
        }
        if (y + 1 < 3) {
            auto dest = Coord{x, y + 1};
            ret.emplace_back(curr, dest);
        }
        return ret;
    }) | std::views::join;

    std::cout << edges.cbegin()->first.first << std::endl;

    // static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<const decltype(edges)>);//  <- does not compile with message that ;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of `g++-13` is the following (when `static_assert` is uncommented):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:31:32: error: static assertion failed
   31 |     static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<const decltype(edges)>);//  <- does not compile with message that ;
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:31:32: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:48,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:47,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/string:54,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/streambuf:43,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:35,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/iterator:66,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:43,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:501:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'range<_Tp>' [with _Tp = const std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::cartesian_product_view<std::ranges::iota_view<int, int>, std::ranges::iota_view<int, int> >, main::._anon_155> >]
/opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:501:21:   in requirements with '_Tp& __t' [with _Tp = const std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::cartesian_product_view<std::ranges::iota_view<int, int>, std::ranges::iota_view<int, int> >, main::._anon_155> >]
/opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:503:22: note: the required expression 'std::ranges::__cust::begin(__t)' is invalid
  503 |         ranges::begin(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-13.2.0/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:504:20: note: the required expression 'std::ranges::__cust::end(__t)' is invalid
  504 |         ranges::end(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
cc1plus: note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail
Compiler returned:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: the problem occured when I tried to pass `edges` to a function, which receives `const reference` to an `input_range`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me slightly respell your check to make things clearer:

```cpp
using E = decltype(edges);
static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<E>);       // ok
static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<E const>); // error
```

The issue here is that a `join` view is *sometimes* not `const`-iterable - it depends on the kind of range you're joining. In particular, `join`ing a range of input ranges is not going to be const-iterable, because the resulting view has to cache state -- even in `begin()` -- which means we cannot iterate as mutable.

The possible source of confusion here is that `edges.cbegin()` does actually work, it's just that in this case it doesn't actually mean `std::as_const(edges).begin()` (which wouldn't compile here). Instead, `cbegin()` simply always exists on range adapters now and reliably returns an actually-constant iterator. Here, `edges` by itself is a range whose reference type is `Edge&` so `edges.cbegin()` gives you an iterator whose reference type is `Edge const&`.